# Filter Eclipse CDT textual search results by program-structural features

Tags: eclipse, search, full-text-search, eclipse-cdt

I want to use Eclipse CDT to search for all occurrences of regular expresion, say `foo(_bar_)*baz` - in the bodies/bodies and declarations of functions/methods meeting a certain criterion. For the example let's make it all functions/methods named `ignore_me` (but within all classes and namespaces).

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this sort of search in Eclipse CDT.

Clang's [AST matchers](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html) provide a rich domain-specific language for expressing queries like yours (and many other kinds), but using them requires writing code (in a clang plugin or standalone clang-based tool). It may be relatively straightforward to write a simple tool that allows you to write a query and searches a codebase for matches. I'm not sure whether such a tool is already available.